# Do I put my interior wall on top of my flooring or under?

Tags: walls, framing

I'm building a 10x16 dry cabin and just finishing up the outside. I want one small room framed in the corner for a utility closet and possibly a composting toilet. I am doing the floor insulation technique where I sandwich rigid foam between two layers of plywood then lvp on top. Where in this stack does the interior wall framing go. Plywood layer 1? 2? Or can I go on top of lvp which would be easiest.

Comment: What type of framing is supporting the first layer of plywood before the foam goes down and the second layer of plywood? Is it clear span or a certain size joists 16" on center? 24" on center?

Comment: Is there any framing between the layers of plywood, or is this a SIP (structural insulated panel)? If there are floor joists, the insulation is purely incidental to the construction and the interior walls belong on top of the subfloor, just like every other house in the USA. If it's a SIP, ask the manufacturer, but I'd guess it's the same, because if you carve through the top layer of plywood and remove the foam, you're also removing most of the "structural" part.

Comment: The answer is definitely _not_ on top of the LVP. Even if it's not designed to be a floating floor, you don't want rough construction on top of finish materials. A) Finish materials are not designed to support any structure (even non-loadbearing) of the house, and B) if there's ever damage to the floor, or you just change your mind, it's a royal pain to cut out the floor around the wall later, rather than the flooring around the wall now.

Comment: 2x10s 16" OC spanning just under 10'